# Is it possible to convert a .Sketch file to an .SVG?

Tags: file-conversion, sketch-3

Is it possible to convert a [Sketch](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/sketch) file to an SVG without actually having Sketch or DrawIt? I know it's theoretically possible since they're both vector, but I use Windows and Linux, so I don't have a Mac to open the files with.

Comment: I looked and did not find a file specification for the .sketch file. So it is not possible to do without first reverse engineering the file format itself. You should contact their official support channels and ask for a file format specification; or ask for platform agnostic conversion bridges (which I suspect their developers wouldn't know or care how to write given that ["Sketch relies on a lot of technology that is exclusive to OS X"](http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/support/faq/02-general/5-windows.html), Whatever magical technologies those are) So I'm not optimistic for you. Sorry :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no "magic" about "Sketch using a lot of technology that is exclusive to OS X" or not.  That statement on Sketch makers' website is in the context that they do not intend to make Sketch app available on linux and on windows.

The real problem you have is as follows:-

The `sketch` file is an sqlite3 file and in it there are (currently at this time of writing) two tables, `meta` and `payload`.  The `payload` table is a single key-value store, storing `main` and and `BLOB` value.  So that's where you get stuck - you will have to figure out how to reverse engineer the `BLOB` if you do not have a Sketch program.

On the other hand, if you do have a Sketch program, you do not need to reverse engineer anything, you can query information from your Sketch file using Sketch Plugin APIs, which are well documented here - http://bohemiancoding.com/sketch/support/developer/ - which will allow you to automate a lot of the tasks if you have a complicated design workflow.  http://zeplin.io is an example of a simple Sketch plugin that pulls out relevant "spec" information for a developer from a designer-created sketch artboard.

But back to your original question, Sketch itself allows you to export SVG files but that assumes you have the Sketch app.  Long story short, unless you reverse engineer the BLOB binary in the sketch file (or use a tool that someone else created that can), you can't programmatically translate sketch files into SVG files without having a Sketch app.

Comment: the `BLOB` in the `payload` table is a `bplist` object (Apple binary plist), which you can open using https://github.com/cclgroupltd/ccl-bplist and 2 lines of code (see the README there). At that point, you can see the vector graphics structure in "clear" text (ccl_bplist loads it as a python dictionary). You'd need to find the match with SVG, and you'd have a converter there. Since it's text, you can at least guess your way around, and make it work with a bit of time on your hands.

Comment: This information is now obsolete: Sketch 43 introduced a new file format, which is essentially just some json files in a zip archive. They also provide a javascript API for working with the new file format, which you can read about here: https://developer.sketchapp.com/reference/api/

Answer (score 24):

[Figma](https://www.figma.com/) is currently free for anyone to sign up and supports both Sketch import and SVG export. It's a fully-featured design tool that's browser-based so it should work on all three major platforms (OS X, Windows, and Linux). File import from Sketch isn't a perfect 1-to-1 mapping with Figma because both apps have slightly different feature sets, but it should get you 99% of the way there.

Comment: You have saved my day, thanks! Figma was working great for me.